# Display Image using Image Path isn't Working

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I saved user image to a folder in my wwwroot folder and saved the image path to my database, **Razor Pages**, now i want to display the same image using the image path, its not working.

Here is my code to save the image

```
if (Imagefile != null && Imagefile.Length > 0)
            {
                var imgpath = @"\Upload\pkgimages\";
                var uploadpth = _env.WebRootPath + imgpath;

                //Create Directory
                if (!Directory.Exists(uploadpth))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadpth);
                }
                //create file
                var uniqueFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(uniqueFilename + "." + Imagefile.FileName.Split(".")[1].ToLower());
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(uploadpth, filename);
                using (var filestream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    Input.ImagePath = fullPath;
                    await Imagefile.CopyToAsync(filestream);
                }
            }

            var today = DateTime.Now;
            var exp = today.AddDays(Input.Duration);
            Input.expDate = exp;
            var pkg= new UserPackages
            {
                Title = Input.Title,
                BeginDate = DateTime.Now,
                ExpDate=Input.expDate,
                Status = "Pending",
                PackageID = pckID,
                UserID = Loginuser,                  
                ImagePath = Input.ImagePath
            };
            await _userPackageDataService.AddUserPackage(pkg)
```

It saves everything correctly to their respective places now to retrieve the these details back and display the uploaded image

here is my code

```
 public async Task OnGetAsync(string ID)
    {          
        Guid _pkgID = Guid.Parse(ID);
        var package= await _userPackageDataService.ReviewPackage(_pkgID);
        var result= _mapper.Map<packageDTO>(package);
        UserPackage= result;
    }
```

then in my **chtml file** I have this markup

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="@Model.UserPackage.ImagePath" alt="Image" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
        </div>
```

I have also tried

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="@Uri.Content(Model.UserPackage.ImagePath)" alt="Image" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
        </div>
```

It returns the full image path wish was saved to the database but image is not rendered on the browser, please what am i missing out here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute of an `img` element expects either a relative or full URL to the image, not a file path.

Assuming that your image folder is in wwwroot, try this instead:

```
<img src="/upload/pkgimages/@(Path.GetFileName(Model.UserPackage.ImagePath))" alt="Image" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to this would be to save the path to the database without the root path. Then in your razor page,

```
<img src="~/@Model.UserPackage.ImagePath" />
```

Look at the new way I added. The root path notation should be added to your path

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply, but none of these answers fixed it, @Mike, is it something with razor pages?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in a misinterpretation of the context in where things are happening.

When you specify `<img src="@Model.UserPackage.ImagePath"` you are setting the path where the file is stored in the **server** not a URL where the browser needs to go to get the image to display.

To achieve what you want, you will need to have an endpoint (controller/action) receiving the file id and returning the file content. Here some seudo-code what might guide you to solve the problem.

1. In the server you would have an action to get the file content:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnGetFile(string id)
{
    var fileData = _someService.GetFileInfo(id);
    return File(fileData.ImagePath, "application/octet-stream", 
                fileData.fileName);
}
```

2. In the HTML `img` tag:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <img src="/image-controller/action/@Model.UserPackage.PackageID" alt="Image" style="width:200px; height:200px;" />
</div>
```